# Remove Duplicates leaving one record

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table namely ORDERS that has multiple duplicate records as the following:

```
ID  SO
1   A
2   A
3   B
4   C
5   A
```

In the above case, i need all duplicate titles and leave one only.

Article B and Article C are fine. I need to remove Articles A, except one.

Sample output should be like this

```
ID  SO
1   A
3   B
4   C
```

Can somebody help me to achieve this. I have to delete all the duplicate rows from my table

Comment: How do you decide which of the records for `Article A`to keep and which to remove?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a **First**, combined with a **Group By**. Something like this:

```
SELECT First(Table1.ID) AS FirstOfID, Table1.SO
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.SO
ORDER BY Table1.SO;
```

Answer (score 0):

This Query Should do, The **GROUP BY** Clause will select distinct values from  **SO** 
column

```
 SELECT * FROM ORDERS GROUP BY SO;
```